# Übersetzung von "more money than when ..."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I have more money than when I started the job.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche?

> Ich habe mehr Geld als, als ich die Arbeit begann.

Es sieht komisch aus, zwei "als" nacheinander zu haben. Ist der Satz überhaupt richtig?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ich habe mehr Geld als, als ich die Arbeit begann.

Das klingt tatsächlich merkwürdig, und eigentlich unvollständig.

Wie [Jan](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/15318/jan) in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/22691/5999) richtig bemerkt, ist hier etwas ausgelassen. Ich würde allerdings eher dazu tendieren, hier explizit den Zeitpunkt einzufügen, auf den sich das erste *als* bezieht:

> Ich habe mehr Geld als zu dem Zeitpunkt, als ich die Arbeit begann.
>
> Ich habe mehr Geld als damals, als ich die Arbeit begann.
>
> Ich habe mehr Geld als zu der Zeit, als ich die Arbeit begann.

Im letzten Fall lässt sich "Zeit" auch als Zeitraum interpretieren (was in diesem Fall wohl auch inhaltlich Sinn ergeben würde), sodass man auch sagen könnte:

> Ich habe mehr Geld als zu der Zeit, während der ich die Arbeit begann.
>
> Ich habe mehr Geld als zu der Zeit, in der ich die Arbeit begann.

Dadurch lässt sich die immer noch etwas unschöne (wenn auch durch mehrere Wörter getrennte) Dopplung von *als* verhindern. Bei anderen Ausdrücken für den Zeitpunkt oder Zeitraum ergibt sich dies zum Teil ohnehin:

> Ich habe mehr Geld als an dem Tag, an dem ich die Arbeit begann.

Alternativ lässt sich diese Dopplung von *als* aber auch dadurch vermeiden, dass man einen der Satzteile umformt:

> Ich habe mehr Geld als zu Beginn meiner Arbeit.

Comment: +1 für "Ich habe mehr Geld **als zu der Zeit**, als ich die Arbeit begann". Das ist genau die Variante, zu der ich greife, um ein doppeltes "als" zu vermeiden.

Answer (score 1):

Du hast recht, die Version mit zwei aufeinanderfolgenden *als* sieht komisch aus, hört sich für den Muttersprachler komisch an, und ist falsch.

In einigen Dialekten (aber nicht standardsprachlich!) kannst du auf eine der folgenden Formen ausweichen:

> Ich habe mehr Geld wie, als ich mit der Arbeit begann.
>   Ich habe mehr Geld als wie, als ich mit der Arbeit begann.

Aber beide sind noch nicht vollständig entholprigt.

Das Problem liegt im Englischen in einem verschluckten Satzteil, den man im Deutschen eben nicht weglassen darf:

> Ich habe mehr Geld, als *ich hatte*, als ich mit der Arbeit begann.
>   Ich habe mehr Geld als *damals*, als ich mit der Arbeit begann.

Vergleiche:

> I have more money than *I had* when I started the job.

Comment: "mehr Geld wie" und "mehr Geld als wie" sind keine Dialekte sondern Fehler. Ich höre das regelmäßig, gelegentlich passiert es mir auch. Aber es ist schlichtweg falsch. – Außerdem empfinde ich "als als" nicht falsch. Es hört sich komisch an, ja. Aber als falsch definiere ich es nicht. Ich würde jedoch versuchen, es anders auszudrücken.

Comment: @Em1 Standardsprachlich ja. Dialekte funktionieren nach anderen Regeln. Wenn der Bayer *der Weps* sagt, dann ist das so »richtig« wie wenn die Bayerin *mehra Goid ois wia du* verdient ;) Ob es schön ist (ich finde, nicht) steht auf einem anderen Blatt.

Comment: Wenn isch de Dinge su ausspreche, wie man ed en d'r Gegend halt maach, dann ess dat Dialekt. Falsche Wortwahl hingegen het nix met Dialekt zo tun.

Answer (score -2):

**Ich hatte mehr Geld, bevor ich arbeitete.** 
This would be right sentence because you have to use the past tense together with the pluperfect and the present tense together with the present perfect tense.
**Ich hatte mehr Geld, bevor ich mit der Arbeit begann.** Would be also right.
The last sentence has a different meaning. This "Arbeit" means the work at home not at work.

Comment: No, these are not the right sentences, because they say the opposite thing. Your sentences' meaning is: "I had more money at the time when I started working than now." And actually, there's no difference between your two sentences. And finally both sentences sound pretty much unidiomatic.